# Update Collection of entities in IQueryable mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I should rewrite SQL code in C# code using EF:

```
UPDATE Submissions SET Other_Platform = (SELECT top 1 Other_Platform FROM Submission_Platform_Other_DistributionMethods WHERE Submission_ID = @SubmissionId )
```

Cause there are to many records in table `Submissions` i don't want to convert this collection into `List` to update field in loop.

Have anybody some ideas? Thanks.

---

```
var otherPlatform = db.Submission_Platform_Other_DistributionMethods.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Submission_ID == subId);
var toUpdate = db.Submissions.Select(s=> UpdateSubmission(otherPlatform));

db.Submissions.AddRange(toUpdate);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This is one possible solution that came to my head - create some method(like mapper) which takes parameter to set as `Other_Platform`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the context alert of the updates you have done. Then I dont think there is any other way than to loop through the collection and update the platform and then saving the changes.

Two other ways you can do however these would mean the changes go past your entities that are loaded in the context and you would have to recreate the context(s).

1) create a stored procedure and execute that with the parameter you are providing

2) execute sqlcommand to the context

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.SqlCommand("<update query here>"); 
}
```

Comment: yes, I believe this is the only way as EF is all about ORM. Even if you use linq or lambda (like `Foreach(d => {.....})`) syntax to process collection for setting value. Internally it iterates over foreach loop and EF will create n no of Update queries while Savechanges is called.